# DataStax API for mapping Java types to Cassandra Types

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

does anyone know of a DataStax API to get what Cassandra native type will be used for a non-annotated field in an @Table pojo? E.g.

`private byte age;` //maps to tinyint

Answer (score 0):

The CQL data type to Java type can be found [here](http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203V0300e/BV030040.HTM). I don't think there is an actual API that will return these values.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the CodecRegistry with a combination of reflective code to get all the available codecs to build a map of Java types to CqlTypes.

**edit**

Obtaining a bean reference to `CassandraMappingContext` is even easier.